# Packages roscpp and std_msgs

Tags: ros, std-msgs, dependencies, roscpp, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In tutorials of wikiros, roscpp, rospy and std_msgs become dependencies of our newly-created package. What I am wondering is what they provide for us.

- For example, I am writing a node, and in this node, we create publisher and send messages to a topic. The messages are are in type of String.msg. In other words, by using std_msgs::String type, I define an msg variable and publish it via in the node. In this case, which dependency provide std_msgs::String type for us ?

Someone told me that all headers defined for messages are provided by roscpp. Dependency of std_msgs package takes role in creating a custom message. If you do not create user-defined message, you do not make std_msgs a dependency for your package. All the headers for the messages are given to you by roscpp.

Is this correct ? I cannot find a resource what these dependencies are for.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333621/packages-roscpp-and-std_msgs/) by [gktg1514](https://answers.ros.org/users/37700/gktg1514/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2019-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> by using std_msgs::String type, I define an msg variable and publish it via in the node. In this case, which dependency provide std_msgs::String type for us ?

`std_msgs::String` is defined in a header part of the `std_msgs` package.

> Someone told me that all headers defined for messages are provided by roscpp. Dependency of std_msgs package takes role in creating a custom message. If you do not create user-defined message, you do not make std_msgs a dependency for your package. All the headers for the messages are given to you by roscpp.
>
> Is this correct ?

No. This is not correct.

For your example already we require `std_msgs` as a dependency, as that package provides the `String` message type.

It also provides a number of other message types, see [the index](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/index-msg.html).

`roscpp` itself (ie: the package) only provides a few services and messages, but those are not typically used as parts of other (ie: custom) messages. See [the index](http://docs.ros.org/api/roscpp/html/index-msg.html) again.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gktg1514](https://answers.ros.org/users/37700/gktg1514/) on 2019-09-23**:
Thank you so much. I examined your "index" links; everything is senseful right now.